# Jackson serialization with ObjectMapper in java

Tags: java, jackson

I want to serialize the different types of lists by using object mapper, but I do not know how to 
  pass the different types of list objects into object Mapper at a time. The following is my code:

```
AccountingService accService      = ServiceFactory.getAccountingService();
List<TaxCategory> taxCategoryList = accService.getAllTaxCategories();
ProductService productService     = ServiceFactory.getProductService();
List<SimpleUom> simpleUomList     = productService.getSimpleUomsList();

ObjectMapper objMapper;
objMapper.writeValueAsString(?)--
```

Would You please suggest what I have to pass instead of ? in above code. This is because of i have to get the jackson serialized string that includes above lists as a single string in jsp and parse that string to get individual lists to be used at client side.

Comment: You are going to want to put those lists into a wrapper object of some sort. Otherwise you are going to have a hell of a time trying to parse out the different item types on the client side.

Answer (score 24):

Simply try:

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = objMapper.writeValueAsString(simpleUomList);
```

---

**Edit according to the comment:**

You need to create a class wrapping your two lists and then write it:

```
public class MyLists {
    private List<TaxCategory> taxCategoryList;
    private List<SimpleUom> simpleUomList;
    // + constructor, getters and setters
}

ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyLists myLists = new MyLists(taxCategoryList, simpleUomList);
String jsonString = objMapper.writeValueAsString(myLists);
```

Comment: Thansk for your response, but i want to send both the lists at a time into objMapper.writeValueAsString(taxCategoryList + simpleUomList);