# Fetch related entities as Base Type

Tags: json, jpa

I'm currently trying to setup a database – using Java only. Given this simple class that might appear in the average social network app:

```
@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String otherInfo;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> contacts;
}
```

When the user logs in, he should receive the basic information and the list of contacts with their basic info, *but not their contacts*. To reduce the amount of boiler-plate code, I want to use a standard solution like Gson. However, even with lazy fetch the whole user is loaded on `gson.toJson(user)`.

Therefore I thought of extracting the basic infos into a base class `BasicUser` and changing the `contacts` to `List<BasicUser>`. Now I only need to somehow circumwent the discriminator column when I fetch the contacts – of course they are all saved as complete users on the server. Unfortunately, I don't know how to archieve that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jackson for serialization, the problem can be solved without writing custom serialization code. `BasicUser` contains the getters of the attributes, I want to serialize:

```
public interface BasicUser {
    String getEmail();
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
}
```

With a single annotation the `contacts` attribute is interpreted as a list of `BasicUser`s:

```
@Entity
public class User implements BasicUser {    
    @Id
    private String email;
    private String firstName;   
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JsonSerialize(contentAs = BasicUser.class)
    private List<User> contacts = new ArrayList<>();    

    // ... implemented getters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get only part of the entity you can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections). In your case it can be, for example, like this:

```
public interface BaseUser {
    String getEmail();
    String getName();
    String getOtherInfo();
}

public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository <User, String> {
    List<BaseUser> findAllBy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to modify your domain model just to accomodate a serialization library.

If you only want certain fields of a collection to be exposed to JSON, you could use Jackson with `@JsonView` (see here: [How to serialize using @Jsonview with nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260464/how-to-serialize-using-jsonview-with-nested-objects)) not sure if Gson provides a similar feature as I have never used it extensively.

Comment: I agree that a separation of persistence and serialisation for network com is preferable. With your towards Jackson I managed to solve my problem although `JsonView`? doesn't do the trick since I can't switch the view based on the depth of the entity graph. 
On the first layer (the logged in user), I want to serialize the `contacts` attribute, but on the second one (contacts of the user) it should be ommitted.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that I had linked to the wrong question. I meant this approach specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34416577/1092818. You  just need to skip `User.contacts` in the `@JsonView` that will be passed to the `JsonSerializer` (your problem is exactly the same as in the question I linked to, except that `A` and `B` are the same)