# JPA : How to create a self-join entity?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a user entity with an assistant column.

Every user has an assistant but there are circles as well.

> For example : User A's assistant is User B and User B's assistant is
>   user A.

**If I use @ManyToOne and @OneToMany annotations, then, there is an infinite recursion when converting objects to JSON, even @JsonManagedReference and 
@JsonBackReference didn't help.**

BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @Version
    private int version;
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "assistant_id")
    private User assistant;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assistant")
    private Set<User> assistants;


}
```

Are there any opportunity in Spring to solve this?

Comment: Post your code!

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference` won't help, because the 'forward' references can still form a cycle, even when the 'inverse' references are not being serialized.

What you want is *probably* for the `User` assigned to the `assistant` property to be serialized without *its own* `assistant` property (so that any cycles break). Essentially, you have the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260464/how-to-serialize-using-jsonview-with-nested-objects), except in your case `A` and `B` are the same class.

Apart from the solution described in the question I've linked to, you'll also want to specify which `@JsonView` to use when serializing the object. See the 'Using JSON Views with Spring' section [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'work'. `assistants` are already loaded lazily by default, just like any other to-many association. Without `@JsonIgnore` Jackson still tries to serialize the property, though, trigerring the lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

Could you create Assistant entity based on the same table and join?

Comment: This isn't seems to be an answer but yes suggestion, so better place for asuggestion would be a comment section of the question.

Comment: I am sorry but this is a solution.